# How can I get Site Collection name(or title) in SPSite level using C#

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, site-collection, site-template, spsite

I am a newbie in SharePoint, and now I`m trying to make a Winform application that analyse

the SharePoint site. My application works like this.

1. Type target site url in text box and click button
2. Analyze the Sites( web application, content database, site collection, web, list)
3. Show the result in each DataGridView

And in Site Collection level, I have a question, is How can I get Site Collection Name(or a title)??

It is same in SPWeb.Title?

Please help me, I`m waiting your advice.....

Answer (score 1):

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("Absolute_URL");
```

`oSiteCollection.PortalName` should give you name of site collection.

You can also get it by `Rootweb` object of SiteCollection and use `Title` property...

Answer (score 0):

[SPSite.PortalName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.portalname.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will returns the Title of Site Collection (RootWeb of Site Collection).

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://Server_Name/sites/Site_Name");
string siteTitle = oSiteCollection.PortalName;
```

You can also get the `RootWeb` Title:

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://Server_Name/sites/Site_Name");
SPWeb rootWeb = oSiteCollection.RootWeb;
string title = rootWeb.Title;
```